# Tabulator mutator doesn't display any data

Tags: tabulator

Given the following table description:

```
<script>
    var customMutator = function(value, data, type, params, component){
        return data.category_name + " " + data.short_description;
    } ;

    var tabledata = [
    {id:1, category_name:"IT", short_description:"This is an IT message", long_description:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", valid_from:"2019-12-05T10:48:00", valid_to:"2018-12-04T22:00:00"},
    {id:2, category_name:"Bookeeping", short_description:"This is an bookeeping message", long_description:"Lorem ipsum dolor azaz sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", valid_from:"2019-12-04T10:48:00", valid_to:"2019-12-04T22:00:00"},
    ];

    var printIcon = function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
        return '<span  style="color:blue;"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></span>';
    };

    var table = new Tabulator("#mb-table", {
        placeholder:"Keine Nachricht vorhanden...",
        height: window.innerHeight - 53,
        layout:"fitColumns",
        langs:{
            "de-de":{
                "headerFilters":{
                    "default":"Filtern..."
                }
            }
        },
        columns:[
            {title:"Kategorie", field:"category_name", headerFilter:true, width:120},
            {title:"Kat", field:"new_kat", mutator:customMutator, headerFilter:true, width:120},
            {title:"Nachricht", field:"short_description", headerFilter:true, formatter:function(cell, formatterParams){
                var val1 = cell.getValue();
                var val2 = cell.getRow().getData().long_description;
                cell.getElement().style.whiteSpace = "pre-wrap";

                return "<span style='font-weight:bold;'>" + val1 + "</span><br><span style='word-break: normal;'>" + val2 + "</<span>";
                }
            },
            {title:"Gültig von", field:"valid_from", headerFilter:true, width:110, sorter:"datetime", sorterParams:{format:"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss"},
                formatter:"datetime", formatterParams:{
                    inputFormat:"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss",
                    outputFormat:"DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm"
                },
            },
            {title:"Gültig bis", field:"valid_to", headerFilter:true, width:110, sorter:"datetime", sorterParams:{format:"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss"},
                formatter:"datetime", formatterParams:{
                    inputFormat:"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss",
                    outputFormat:"DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm"
                },
            },
            {formatter:printIcon, align:"center", width:10, headerSort:false,
                cellClick:function(e, cell){alert("Printing row data for: " + cell.getRow().getData().id)}},
            {formatter:"buttonCross", width:10, align:"center", headerSort:false,
                cellClick:function(e, cell){alert("Printing row data for: " + cell.getRow().getData().category_name)}},
        ]
    });

    table.setLocale("de-de");
    table.setData(tabledata);
</script>
```

I do not see anything displayed in the Kat column.
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Actually the mutator function is not even invoked.
If I place console.log(data); (before the return, of course) into the function I cannot see anything in the console

Answer (score 1):

upgrading to V. 4.5.3 has solved that issue.

Comment: a number of updates to the mutation system happened in the 4.5.3 to make the behaviour more consistent